# Why is Django admin login giving me 403 CSRF error?

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf

I am running Django 1.2.2 and I get the following error when I try to log in to the Django admin:

> Forbidden (403) CSRF verification
>   failed. Request aborted.
>
> Reason given for failure:
>
> No CSRF or session cookie.

** I have made NO customization to the barebones admin and when I inspect the source there is a CSRF token in the form in what I believe is the correct place.

When I look at the actual request that is being sent there is a csrf token being sent but Django still says CSRF verification failed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Why is this happening?

Comment: Didn't Django 1.2.2 come out yesterday?

Comment: Yeah I revised my question. I deleted and reinstalled Django today. I was getting the error before doing that though. I was using 1.2.1 before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Do you have `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in your `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` ?

2) Are you sure you've always been on 1.2.2? That only came out last night...

Comment: Yes I have it in my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. Actually I think I was running 1.2.1 till this morning when I completely reinstalled it. Good catch.

Comment: If I inspect the request in Charles I can see that there is a csrfmiddlewaretoken in the request. So CSRF is working if the token is being generated. But why is it not seeing the token when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem on Django 1.2.1 FINAL. Since I knew that Django on our production site would never be updated from 1.0 (for various reasons), I found a workaround which I implemented into my development version of settings.py, leaving the production settings.py untouched.

Create a **middleware.py** file in your application directory with the following code:

```
class disableCSRF:
    def process_request(self, request):
        setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
        return None
```

Then in your development version of settings.py, insert this into MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

```
'your_app_name.middleware.disableCSRF',
```

Perhaps not the safest solution, but our Django site is strictly internal, so there is a minimum risk for any type of malicious actions. This solution is simple and doesn't involve changes to templates/views, and it worked instantly (unlike other I've tried).

Hopefully someone in a similar situation to mine will find this useful.

Credit goes to John McCollum, on whose [site](http://johnmc.co/llum/disable-csrf-protection-for-django-1-2/) I've found this.

Comment: Do you mean to say "project" instead of "app" here?

Comment: When I try this solution it just gives me an error at the admin login: "Looks like your browser isn't configured to accept cookies. Please enable cookies, reload this page, and try again."

Comment: I had to use this method. For some reason the server of my work is cleaning the cookies. We thought it was due to whitespaces, but it is still throwing errors. Thanks for this cool solution!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works), not only do you need the csrf hidden form field, but also the `csrftoken` cookie. The error message you provided also suggests a missing cookie.

I would look in your browser's cookies to ensure the `csrftoken` cookie is present.

Comment: I finally figured out that I was only getting this error in Firefox. To correct this problem I went into my firefox cookies and deleted all of them for the django site. Once the browser had a new csrf cookie for the site it worked fine. Must have been an out of date cookie or something...

Comment: I am having this problem again with the same site. The solution I said above is not working this time around. Django is not even generating a CSRF cookie now.