# CSRF Verification failing for some users

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-csrf

I'm getting complaints from a user who is constantly getting a CSRF 403 error when he tries to login to my site (using django.contrib.auth.views.login).

I don't get this error myself, and have no other users complaining of the issue.  Any idea what it could be?  How should I go about debugging this?

Is there a way to log detailed information about CSRF failures so I can try to inspect the user's state when they login.  I don't want to turn DEBUG=True for an external user...

Comment: Has he tried clearing his cookies, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678238/why-is-django-admin-login-giving-me-403-csrf-error/3680604#3680604 ?

Comment: Yes, he has tried multiple computers, browsers, and connection types.  I'm able to login through his account just fine.  He is in Australia -- so his timezone is different -- but that doesn't seem like it should be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply to my comment, I am not sure what is causing this issue. I would use [CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#csrf-failure-view) to implement a custom view that would give you more information about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into that and it turned out to be a cookie problem, as in the end user had them disabled.