# Django admin login returns Forbidden 403 CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django

Pretty new to Django. Working through a second project following the Polls tutorial on Django website. Previous effort went well, albeit simple. This time around encountering problems accessing admin login.

I have created a superuser and using those credentials, when I try to login to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/` I get the following error:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF cookie not set.
```

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678238/why-is-django-admin-login-giving-me-403-csrf-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573163/django-admin-login-suddenly-demanding-csrf-token), most answers either detail clearing browser cookies (did that), include `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in your middleware (which I do), or creating an exemption or workaround.

1) My question is why the admin portal does not seem to work now, but it did for my previous project and I am following the same steps?

2) Shouldn't the properties for the admin panel be inherited through the project initiation?

3) How would I set the CSRF for admin when [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/) appears to state that the CSRF middleware is activated by default?

Thanks for any help.

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for aptly project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import dj_database_url

from .secret_settings import *

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'../search')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'search',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'aptly.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'aptly.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "db_name",
        "USER": "me",
        "PASSWORD": "",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "",
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
)

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

#DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**Directory**

```
project
-aptly
--settings.py
--urls.py
--wsgi.py
-search
--templates
---index.html
--models.py
--urls.py
--views.py
manage.py
```

Comment: Are you using `custom html templates` for admin login page?

Comment: @cutteeth No. I added the urls.py so you can see here. I have a number of html templates I am working on but none of them should be confused for the admin login page.

Comment: add your view where you call template this probably cause troubles

Comment: The only solution I found for similar problem was add `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '127.0.0.1'` in settings file as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42115353/2343488)

Comment: Added this to your settings.py `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.yourdomain.com',]`

Answer (score 6):

add this to your settings.py and it will work
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://example.com']

Answer (score 5):

You are setting `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')`
Remove this line and see if that solves your issue. If you are enabling https `csrf will work only as per the specifications of https`. There is a possibility that you are enabling https and serving your website from a non-https server. Also, Have you tried in another browser after clearing cookies or in private/incognito mode? Sometimes this error occurs because `csrf cookie is not set correctly`. Try `inspecting your request/response headers` from browser console.

Comment: I removed `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` entirely from settings.py but error remains.

Comment: can you post your entire settings.py and also the structure of your template directory? Are you running you server using `./manage.py runserver`?

Comment: just uploaded entire `settings.py`. Yes, I am running `./manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 2):

Spend some hours debugging this problem. None of the above fixed it.

What finally worked for me is disabling browser extensions. Some custom packages on my dev machine seemed to remove the CSRF token somehow.

Answer (score 1):

remove browser cookies and refresh the admin page

Comment: This post looks like a comment for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why this is the answer, but I went in and updated my Django to the current release. For whatever reason this solved the problem...

```
pip install --upgrade django==1.10.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem had occurred with me too.

Actually the problem was that the my **Django app** was not using the **dependencies** from **virtual environment** even it was activated.

I had installed **Django 1.8** in **my system** and **Django 1.11.2** in  **virtual environment**.

So the problem was with the **Django version**.

Finally I fixed issues as follows,

1) Deleted/Renamed  **virtualenv** and created new one

```
rm -rf venv && virtualenv venv
```

2) Activated **virtualenv**

on **MAC**

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

**on Windows**

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

3) Installed **dependencies** from **pip-requirements.txt** file(If you have otherwise you will need to install dependencies separately)

```
pip install -r pip-requirements.txt
```

4) After that I started start development server(**python manage.py runserver**) and try to login. It will work.

Check [pip freeze does not show all installed packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960199/pip-freeze-does-not-show-all-installed-packages/45207675#45207675) also.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one of the answers, could be browser plugins removing cookies / CSRF..
I opened the same page in safari and it worked.